# Hiding Database Configuration - Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

So I just finished my first php codeigniter application, and I am about to deploy it to a server.  However, I've heard it's very bad practice to keep database settings in your document root. Does Codeigniter somehow hide the settings in application/config/database.php or should I move the entire application folder elsewhere and reference it from index.php?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always move the application and system folders outside of `docroot`. This way, no application files are accessible from the web, just the bootstrap.

In a default CI install, you get this:

```
public_html // the docroot folder
  application
  system
  index.php
```

I change it like this:

```
application
system
public_html // the docroot folder
  index.php
```

And change index.php to this:

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be bad practice if you're file is publicly accessable, but it's not a bad thing on its own. For example, WordPress (a CMS that powers a large part of the net) stores it's database config information in the document root in a file called `wp-config.php`.

The advice we follow in WordPress land is to chmod the file to `755` such that it's only readable by auth'ed users and Apache.

```
sudo chmod 755 file.ext
```

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter includes `.htaccess` files in the `application/` and `/system` folders that deny access however it's always a good idea to move these folders out of any publicly accessible folders.

The CodeIgniter front controller (`index.php`) contains variables for changing the application and system folder locations.